# Tagged Blade component with variable name

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

i have a view where a different tagged component should be rendered depending by the value of a variable where the name is stored. For example

```
@if( $a['type'] == 'component' )
    "<x-{$a['name']} />"
@endif
```

But i can't find how to do it the right way, because using brakets `{{ }}` will also print them on the page ( before and after the component ).

The component class also has some function that is being called, so the `@component` directive would only solve a part of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I might have figured out the solution and i will post it in here for reference. It currently works but i can't say it won't give me some trouble later on, In case you find a better approach i will be happy to have a look.

After having created a few blade components as usual

```
php artisan make:component MyComponent1
php artisan make:component MyComponent2
php artisan make:component MyComponent3
```

and having declared all needed properties and methods, you can either include the components inside a view the regular way

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        @if($somethingHappens)
            <x-my-component1 a="" b="" :c="$c" class="" />
        @elseif ($somethingElseHappens)
            <x-my-component2 a="" b="" :c="$c" class="" />
        @else
            <x-my-component3 a="" b="" :c="$c" class="" />
        @endif
    </body>
</html>
```

Or, in case you would like more flexibility deciding what component should be used at runtime and generate the component tags somewhere else outside the view, i have found this solution

```php
//some code.....

return('myview')->with([
    'type' => 'component',
    'component' => '<x-my-component3 a="" b="" :c="$vars[\'c\']" class="" />',
    'vars' => [ 'c' => 'somevalue' ]
]);


#################

//myview.blade.php

<html>
    <head></head
    <body>

    @php
        if($type == 'component')

            echo compileStringComponent(
                $component,
                $__env,
                $vars 
            );
    @endphp

    </body>
</html>

################

//file containing the function

use Illuminate\View\Factory as ViewFactory;

//This function takes the whole tagged component as string and returns the corresponding html

function compileStringComponent(string $component, ViewFactory $__env, $vars = null )
{
    $compiled = Blade::compileString($component);

    ob_start();

        try {

            eval('?>'.$compiled);

        } catch (\Exception $e){

            ob_get_clean(); 
        throw( $e);

        }

        $content = ob_get_clean();

    return $content;
  }
```

A few notes:

1) Blade::compileString returns a compiled string to be evaluated, and inside the code there are a few references to the $__env variable which is an instance of Illuminate\View\Factory and exists inside the view already. This means that if the function is called outside the view, the $__env variable must be passed to the caller

2) The $vars array is needed in case data is passed to the component through the :attributes for the same reason as above, because those variables will not exist inside the caller and must be passed to it

3) ob_start() and ob_get_clean() are used to avoid sending incomplete views to the user in case any error arises.

I hope it will helps somebody